How can my VersionedTransaction that uses a LUT be too large?
I am trying to transfer SPL tokens from 25 wallets to 1 wallet.
I have already extended my LUT with all source-and-destination pubkeys-and-ata's
I double checked all accounts are in the LUT.
I am compiling my all of my intsructions (25) into a MessageV0 and sending a VersionedTransaction while providing all relevant keypairs.
I use Python
'''
Instructions_list = [transfer_checked(transfer_param)for transfer_param in transfer_params_list]

lut_account = LUT_Mgr.get_LUT_acount(token_accounts, fee_payer) #my custom function

blockhash = solana_client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash

message = MessageV0.try_compile(payer=fee_payer.pubkey(),
                 instructions=Instructions_list,
                 address_lookup_table_accounts=[lut_account], #with LUT
                 recent_blockhash=blockhash)

transaction= VersionedTransaction(message=message, keypairs= [fee_payer, *source_keypairs])

response = solana_client.send_transaction(transaction,opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False))

'''
The result is ->
InvalidParamsMessage {    message: "base64 encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction too large: 3768 bytes (max: encoded/raw 1644/1232)",}
My understanding is that the size limit is for Legacy transactions not for versioned tx combined with a LUT! how is that possible?

Signers and invoked program accounts cannot be indexed into a lookup table.  If you are trying to transfer from 25 wallets, I assume that means your transaction has 25 signatures which eats up 800 bytes (25 * 32) for the signer accounts and 1600 bytes for the signatures (25 * 64).

hmm, i guess your answer makes sense, do you mind sharing a source explaining this ?

Wrt accounts, here in the Solana Labs code you can see how they filter out write and read accounts which are not signers and not invoked.  Here in the table proposal, in the limitations, they mention that signers may not be loaded via lookup tables.
Wrt signatures, Solana uses ed25519 keys which have 64 byte signatures.
